# Implementing Alipay to OpenCart

Tags: php, mysql, e-commerce, opencart

*I have to preface this question by saying, yes, I am aware this is a little of an open ended question. Feel free to let me know if you want it removed.*

I am currently developing a module that would implement Alipay to OpenCart. OpenCart comes with various payment gateways such as Amazon or PayPal, but since we are targeting the Chinese demographic, we have to use Alipay.

I have successfully implemented the Alipay framework to my dev/staging site with dummy data and products, so I know I am able to make valid requests and pay real money to our customer's account.

Here is what I am need of a little assistance - I am not quite sure how to implement my existing Alipay API into OpenCart.

Here is my Alipay file structure at the moment:

1. `alipay_index.html`. This is my Alipay index file which contains hidden dummy data such as the item name, price, transaction number, description, etc. This data would come from a MySQL database in the future.
2. `alipayapi.php`. This is the page that generates the request (using POST from the various inputs from `alipay_index.html`), and sends the requests to Alipay's API files under `/libs/`.
3. Within `/libs/` is a PHP file called `alipay.config.php` which contains all the sensitive information such as our Alipay Partner ID, MD5 hash key, various certificates, etc. Under `/libs/` is also various Alipay API files such as `notify_url.php`, `return_url.php`, `alipay_submit.class.php` (which builds and sends the request URL).

From my understanding, OpenCart allows for the editing of module information in `admin`, that allows modifying attributes such as "which layouts to display the module on, whether it is enabled or disabled, and any module specific options", taken from the [OpenCart docs](http://docs.opencart.com/display/opencart/Developing+modules). I can imagine the information of `alipay.config.php` being in this edit page, so administrators can change the partner ID, key, and certificate location, etc.

My question is - I am entirely not sure where to start. I have completed the Hello World tutorials that one could find online, but since I am dealing with the Alipay API and so many different inputs, I am quite lost. Could someone with OpenCart experience give me some pointers on what steps I can take?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenCart is implemented in some kind of MVC pattern. In order to implement a new *payment module* you could take a look at any of the already existing (bundled) payment modules. Pick any of them or more of them that could suit you the most and start by copying and editing it.

The payment module files are located at these folders:

- admin

  - `admin/controller/payment/` - controller classes
  - `admin/model/language/<LANG>/payment/` - translation files
  - `admin/view/template/payment/` - templates
- catalog

  - `catalog/controller/payment/` - controller classes
  - `catalog/model/payment/` - model classes
  - `catalog/model/language/<LANG>/payment/` - translation files
  - `admin/view/theme/<THEME>/template/payment/` - templates

Pick e.g. PayPal, copy it, rename to *AliPay*, rename each occurrence of *paypal* to *alipay* within the files, add/remove setting options and off you go ;-)

Comment: This is how I ended up doing it.. It makes me feel like I'm not learning much while doing so, but it gets the job done, and well, with less time.

Comment: Exactly, but you are also learning somehow because you need to realize what are you doing and why you are doing it and with that you can learn how things are working together in OpenCart.